# Swift 4: tuple as optional

Tags: swift, tuples

New to swift. From what I understand, tuple assignment operator '?'  isn't allow with tuple.

```
var optionalTuple = (String, Int)? // this isn't allowed.
```

Is there a work around besides assigning the elements as optional individually?

Comment: I think it should be ` var optional:(String,Int)? ` equals to is for assignment

Comment: `(String, Int)?` is  a *type,* not a value. Do you want to declare a variable or assign a value to it? What do you mean by *"assigning the elements as optional individually"*? What is the expected result?

Comment: Just trying to find if I can declare a tuple  as optional, not the elements:       var optionalVariable1: String?
var optionalVariable2: Int?
var optionalTuple = (optionalVariable1,optionalVariable2). I beleive kathayatnk is right. var optional:(String,Int)?

Comment: @kathayatnk    Where to read about this?

Comment: `var optionalInt = Int?` would not compile either. Your error is unrelated to tuples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(String, Int)?` is a type, not a value, so it cannot be put on the right hand side of `=`.

If you didn't know already, when you declare a variable/constant, you can specify its type using this syntax:

let/var name: Type

So an optional tuple declaration looks like this:

```
var optionalTuple: (String, Int)?
```

Another way to do it is this:

```
var optionalTuple = (String, Int)?.none
```

The above two will have the value of `nil`. You can also initialise this to a custom value:

```
var optionalTuple: (String, Int)? = ("Hello", 10)
```

Another way to do this is:

```
var optionalTuple = (String, Int)?.some(("Hello", 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Tuples **can** be declared as optional, but you seem to be confusing the type and the value.

```
//Type is optional tuple (String, Int), value is nil
let optionalTuple : (String, Int)? = nil       

//Type is optional tuple (String, Int), value is ("James", 27)
let optionalTuple : (String, Int)? = ("James", 27)   

//Type is (inferred) optional tuple (String, Int). Value is ("James", 27)
let optionalTuple = ("James", 27)
```

With some unit tests so you can run and see for yourself:

```
func testTupleOptionality() {

    func returnOptionalTuple(returnNil:Bool) -> (String, Int)? {
        if returnNil {
            return nil
        }
        else {
            return ("James", 27)
        }
    }

    let result1 = returnOptionalTuple(returnNil: true)
    XCTAssertNil(result1)

    let result2 = returnOptionalTuple(returnNil: false)
    XCTAssertNotNil(result2)
    XCTAssertEqual(result2!.0, "James")
    XCTAssertEqual(result2!.1, 27)
}

func testTupleOptionalityVariable() {
    let optionalTuple : (String, Int) = nil
    XCTAssertNil(optionalTuple)
}
```